# How to pass arguments to an external function that I am calling using CallInst::Create(...) in my LLVM pass?

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-ir

So this is what I am trying to do:

```
     if(isa<CallInst>(&(*BI)) )
                {
        ArrayRef <Value *> arguments('c');
        StringRef fname = cast<CallInst>(&(*BI))->getCalledFunction()->getName();
        errs()<<fname + " was called\n";
        //CallInst *CI = dyn_cast<CallInst>(BI);
        if(fname=="pthread_mutex_lock"){
            Instruction *newInst = CallInst::Create(hook, arguments, "");
            BB->getInstList().insert(BI, newInst);
        }
```

where "hook" is the function. The error I get is:

> no matching constructor for initialization of
>         'ArrayRef'
>                           ArrayRef  arguments('c');

And when I change `ArrayRef <Value *> arguments('c')`to `ArrayRef <char> arguments('c')` the error becomes:

> no matching function for call to 'Create'
>                                   Instruction *newInst = CallInst::Create(hook, argume...
>                                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   /.../llvm/IR/Instructions.h:1187:20:
>   note: 
>         candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'ArrayRef' to
>         'ArrayRef' for 2nd argument   static CallInst *Create(Value *Func,
>                      ^ /.../llvm/llvm-3.4/include/llvm/IR/Instructions.h:1200:20:
>   note: 
>         candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'ArrayRef' to
>         'const llvm::Twine' for 2nd argument   static CallInst *Create(Value *F, const Twine &NameStr = "",
>                      ^ /.../llvm/llvm-3.4/include/llvm/IR/Instructions.h:1204:20:
>   note: 
>         candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'ArrayRef' to
>         'const llvm::Twine' for 2nd argument   static CallInst *Create(Value *F, const Twine &NameStr,
>                      ^ /.../llvm/llvm-3.4/include/llvm/IR/Instructions.h:1194:20:
>   note: 
>         candidate function not viable: requires 4 arguments, but 3 were provided   static CallInst *Create(Value *Func,
>                      ^

I lack the understanding to passing arguments to external functions I call in my LLVM pass as I am new to this stuff. Help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CallInst::Create needs ArrayRef < Value* > for arguments

so now when you initialized ArrayRef < Value * > arguments('c'), here as there is no inbuilt constructor to convert char 'c' to Value*

you can do

```
ArrayRef< Value* > arguments(ConstantInt::get(Type::getInt8Ty(llvmContext), 'c'));
```

or
you can directly pass single i8 type integer to CallInst::Create call

```
Instruction *newInst = CallInst::Create(hook, ArrayRef< Value* >{ConstantInt::get(Type::getInt8Ty(llvmContext), 'c')}, "");
```

see http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1CallInst.html and http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1ArrayRef.html#details for more details.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I am now able to pass a character. But how about a character array (I want to pass a string)?

Comment: try llvm::ConstantDataArray::get(context, string)    see http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1ConstantDataArray.html

Comment: What does your external function look like?